# Call Method of interface object

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IPropertyEditor
{
    string GetHTML();
    string GetCSS();
    string GetJavaScript();
}
```

I want to get all the classes which inherit from the IPropertyEditor and call the methods and get the return values.

I have been trying and the best I have done by serching is the following.

```
var type = typeof(IPropertyEditor);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));

foreach (var item in types)
{
    string html = (string)item.GetMethod("GetHTML").Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(item, null), null);
}
```

The problem is that it throws the following exception:

```
MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'MyAdmin.Interfaces.IPropertyEditor' not found.
```

I think that the CreateInstance method thinks that the type is a class and tries to create an instance, but it fails because the type is an interface.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: the filter will include interface. make sure type is a class and not abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to exempt `IPropertyEditor` (itself) from `types`

```
var type = typeof(IPropertyEditor);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => p.IsClass && !p.IsAbstract && type.IsAssignableFrom(p));

foreach (var item in types)
{
    string html = (string)item.GetMethod("GetHTML").Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(item, null), null);
}
```

if you are sure that there is no abstract method, you can also use

```
.Where(p => p != type && type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

Answer (score 2):

The filter will include interface. Make sure the filtered type is a class and not abstract to ensure that it can be initialized.

```
.Where(p => 
    p.IsClass &&
    !p.IsAbstract &&
    type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

Also based on the activator used the assumption is that the classes being activated have a default constructor.